# Close button on mobile registration process

Tags: mobile, registration, call-to-action

I am working on a registration process for a mobile site which uses a progress tracker. On completion of the registration the user is instructed that they need to check their email to activate their account. Below the message I've added a 'close' button so the user can close the browser window as their journey has come to an end. I did think to put 'exit' on the button but wasn't sure if that was clear enough. Are there any other suggestions or best practice anyone has come across which relate to this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the user needs an extra link to help close their browser window, as there's already a standard close button that they know how to use.

Instead, suggest that they've completed registration, and tell them that they *can* close the window. And, even better, have a button to go to what they were trying to do before they registered (like commenting on a SO post!)

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the context, I would be more inclined to link someone back to login page or homepage after this type of registration. This way, they could have some options if they haven't received an email/spam etc.

However, if you're set on your initial approach I would go with something like:

Thank you + check email to activate message.
Btn - 'Close Window'

Comment: Thanks for the feedback on this. I don't want to add any 'extra step' for the user but want them to know this is the end of the journey and they have the functionality to close the browser window after the reading the messaging.